# Eloquent Laravel Relationship - user is either be a student or a teacher one to one relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im having problem using eloquent. I have a `user` table (`id`, `name`, `email`, `roleid`) and 2 other tables (`student` and `teacher`).

I want to connect it to `user` table via `roleid` (user table) and `user_id` (`student` and `teacher` table) but I cant seem to show/view it when 2 tables(student and teacher) have data.

This is working when e.g. `student` table has one record and `teacher` dont have

heres my user model

```
//User Model
public function student(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Student','user_id');

    }
    public function teacher(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Teacher','user_id');
    }



//Student and Teacher Model
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id');
    }



//Teacher Controller
public function teacher(){
        $teachers = Teacher::orderBy('t_fname','asc')->paginate(10);
        $users = User::orderBy('username','asc')->paginate(10);
        //$teachers = Teacher::orderBy('name','asc')->paginate(10);
         return view('usersaccount.teacher', compact('teachers','users'));
    }


//View Teacher
@if (count($teachers)>0)
                        @foreach($users as $user)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$user->username}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->teacher->t_fname}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                                <td>
                                     @if(!Auth::guest())
                                        @if(Auth::user()->id == $user->teacher->created_by)
                                            {!!Form::open(['action'=>['TeacherController@destroy', $user->id], 'method'=>'Post', 'class'=>''])!!}
                                            {{Form::hidden('title',$user->username)}}
                                            {{Form::hidden('desc',$user->email)}}
                                            {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
                                            {{Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm delete'] )  }}
                                            {{-- {{Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger delete'])}} --}}
                                            <a href="/teacher/{{$user->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" data-target=".edit{{$user->id}}" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> </a>
                                            {!!Form::close()!!}
                                        @endif
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
```

Comment: I'd use [One To One (Polymorphic)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code is not working if you have data in both the student and teacher table is because both are using the same field of the user data `user_id`.

The correct way to set up your database and models in your case would be to use a One to One polymorphic relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

1. Remove the `user_id` column and relationship from the teacher and student tables and models.
2. Add the following columns to users:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('userable_id');
$table->string('userable_type');
```

3. Edit the models as follows:

Student and Teacher models:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'userable');
}
```

User model:

```
public function userable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Calling `$user->userable` will now return either a teacher or a student.

Comment: already done this, thanks what should be my controller and pass it to my view
  foreach ($users->userable as $info)
                        {{$info->s_name }}
  endforeach

Comment: hi super its working now thank you. how can i show data in a not using a user::find(1) and get all students at one call or teacher thanks

Comment: `Student::with('user')->get()` will give you all students for example.